# Django only serves index page, 404 on all others

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, server, digital-ocean

I have a simple django app im trying to throw up on digital ocean.  I have configured NGINX to proxy my port and serve the static files.  However, when I click on any link to go to another page, it 404s on me.  It only serves the index page correctly, everything else is a 404.

If any of you back-end wizards have any other do's/don't's that i'm currently doing, feel free to add those in your response.

I'm very new to NGINX so please dumb it down :) Thanks.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location /static {
            alias /home/rchampin/ryan_the_developer_django/static;
    }

    location / {
             # First attempt to serve request as file, then
             # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
             # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
             # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've explicitly instructed nginx to return 404 on non file requests. You don't need to do this. Django can manage `Error 404`s. You only need to add a 404.html in your template directory and Django will have this page shown when there's a `404 Not Found Error`.

Plus you don't need to hard code your index page, what's the point of using Django. Michał Karzyński has a very good documentation on how to setup Nginx with Django:

[Setting up Django with Nginx, Gunicorn, virtualenv, supervisor and PostgreSQL](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)

Comment: Thank you so much!